# Lower monitor resolution no scaling but don't center

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

I have second monitor on which I want to lower resolution with scaling disabled. This part works. However, the image is centered which is something I do not like. Is there any way to have the image aligned to one side of the monitor instead of centered?

It seems like it should be possible but I cannot find a setting for that.

Comment: Are you asking about the desktop wallpaper (background image)?

Comment: no, I mean resolution of the display itself...

Comment: Is this a proper summation? You have set the resolution to something that leaves unused (blank) area on the monitor and want to move the used area to one side of the monitor.

Comment: Yes :) Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The monitor's native resolution is the only one that should be used (and scaling adjusted for better visuals whenever needed). It seems you want to do the exact opposite of what you should be doing. Setting a 4:3 resolution for a Widescreen monitor will result in what you're seeing now and it can't be "fixed".

Comment: @MichaelBay dumb reason, I have two monitors over each other and the bttom one has top 2 cms covered by the upper one; so like this I could use both without need to invest into more hardware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the resolution to something that leaves unused (blank) area on the monitor and want to move the used area to one side of the monitor.

At this point you may attempt to use the monitor's menu to attempt to change the X,Y positioning but that may not adjust it all the way to the edge.

Comment: This monitor doesn't support this (sadly) but I can shuffle them around and get the one which does to the bottom position. Thanks